# SSRS - subreports export

Tags: reporting-services, export, subreport

I have created a Report which contains several subreports.

- 1 Subreport will generate
- The other subreports are hidden

This works really well when i use a browser to view the rerports or when i export them to Excel. **edit: Excel, not XML**

When i try to export them to XML, CVS, ... I get errors from the other subreports because they can't execute.

- Is there something I'm overlooking?
- Can someone tell me a fix of trick I can use, that would be most helpfull!
- Or is this a bug from SSRS?

Thanks in advance!

Frederic

**Extra:**

*What are the errors you get? Did you debug yet or find any similar issues on the web that may or may not be the same as your case?*

I only pass the parameters to 1 subreport, the other reports are hidden and **can't** be generated. I can pass the parameters but i would get errors from the datasets inside the other subreports + they would retrieve data which is not showed and is not needed.

> One or more parameters were not specified for the subreport,
>   'report2', located at: /Reports/rp_report2. (rrRenderingError) One or
>   more parameters were not specified for the subreport, 'report2',
>   located at: /Reports/rp_report2.

I already searched on internet but haven't found anything.

*Does it happen only on XML and CSV?*

It works fine for HTML, PDF and Excel. It doesn't work for XML, CSV (comma delimited) and TXT (Tab Delimited Text File). Also the TIFF works fine but isn't used.

Comment: What are the errors you get? Did you debug yet or find any similar issues on the web that may or may not be the same as your case? Does it happen only on XML and CSV? Also, you say "This works really well...when i export them to XML" but also "When i [export to XML] ... I get errors"?

Comment: It works fine while export to Excel, not XML (typo, corrected my post)

Answer (score 0):

The formats  XML and CSV require a special data element ([DataElementOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/rendering-data-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15)) in the rdl:

```
<TablixCell>
    <DataElementOutput>NoOutput</DataElementOutput>
    <CellContents>  
        <Subreport Name="report2">
        <ReportName>report2</ReportName>
        <Parameters>
```